# Project Euler problem 11 in C isnt providing any output

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix

I have been trying to solve Project Euler problem 11. I have rechecked my code multiple times but still, after debugging, my program is not providing any answers

The question states that we need to find the greatest product possible of 4 consecutive numbers: either vertically, horizontally or diagonally of the matrix given in the code below:

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int matr[20][20] =
   {
    {8,  2,  22, 97, 38, 15, 0,  40, 0,  75, 4,  5,  7,  78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8},
    {49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4,  56, 62, 0},
    {81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3,  49, 13, 36, 65},
    {52, 70, 95, 23, 4,  60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1,  32, 56, 71, 37, 2,  36, 91},
    {22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80},
    {24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3,  45, 2,  44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50},
    {32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70},
    {67, 26, 20, 68, 2,  62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8,  40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21},
    {24, 55, 58, 5,  66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72},
    {21, 36, 23, 9,  75, 0,  76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0,  61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95},
    {78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3,  80, 4,  62, 16, 14, 9,  53, 56, 92},
    {16, 39, 5,  42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0,  17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57},
    {86, 56, 0,  48, 35, 71, 89, 7,  5,  44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58},
    {19, 80, 81, 68, 5,  94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4,  89, 55, 40},
    {4,  52, 8,  83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7,  97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66},
    {88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3,  46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69},
    {4,  42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8,  46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36},
    {20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4,  36, 16},
    {20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1,  74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5,  54},
    {1,  70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1,  89, 19, 67, 48}
   };


    int horProduct=0, verProduct=0, diagright=0, diagleft=0;
    int maxProduct = 0;

   // horizontal product
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
       {
            horProduct = matr[i][j]*matr[i][j+1]*matr[i][j+2]*matr[i][j+3];
       }
       if(horProduct > maxProduct)
       {
            maxProduct = horProduct;
       }
   }

   //vertical product
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
       {
            verProduct = matr[i][j]*matr[i+1][j]*matr[i+2][j]*matr[i+3][j];
       }
       if(verProduct > maxProduct)
       {
            maxProduct = verProduct;
       }
   }

   //diagonal right
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
       {
            diagright = matr[i][j]*matr[i+1][j+1]*matr[i+2][j+2]*matr[i+3][j+3];
       }
       if(diagright > maxProduct)
       {
            maxProduct = diagright;
       }
   }

   //diagonal left
    for (int i = 19; i > 3; i--)
   {
       for(int j = 19; j > 3; j--)
       {
            diagleft = matr[i][j]*matr[i-1][j-1]*matr[i-2][j-2]*matr[i-3][j-3];
       }
       if(diagleft > maxProduct)
       {
            maxProduct = diagleft;
       }
   }

   printf("final largest product: %d\n", maxProduct);

   return 0;
}
```

kindly let me know what is going wrong here. Why isn't my program able to print any output?

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug this? Narrow the problem down. Remove all but on of your loops and see what happens. If that one works then try the next and so on. Take a close look at this line and see if you spot the issue: `for (int i = 0; j < 17; i++)`

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j < 17; j++) { horProduct = matr[i][j]*matr[i][j+1]*matr[i][j+2]*matr[i][j+3]; } if(horProduct > maxProduct) { ... }` calculates 17 products each overwriting the last.  Then when it have calculated the last it compares with the max product.  But that isn't what you meant to do...

Comment: how very foolish of me. Thank u for finding it out!!!

Comment: For future reference, you can make your debugging experience easier if you make a [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case, the minimal aspect would be a smaller dimension for `matr`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a rookie mistake.
The comparison with maxProduct should be inside the second loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int matr[20][20] =
   {
    {8,  2,  22, 97, 38, 15, 0,  40, 0,  75, 4,  5,  7,  78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8},
    {49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4,  56, 62, 0},
    {81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3,  49, 13, 36, 65},
    {52, 70, 95, 23, 4,  60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1,  32, 56, 71, 37, 2,  36, 91},
    {22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80},
    {24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3,  45, 2,  44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50},
    {32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70},
    {67, 26, 20, 68, 2,  62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8,  40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21},
    {24, 55, 58, 5,  66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72},
    {21, 36, 23, 9,  75, 0,  76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0,  61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95},
    {78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3,  80, 4,  62, 16, 14, 9,  53, 56, 92},
    {16, 39, 5,  42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0,  17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57},
    {86, 56, 0,  48, 35, 71, 89, 7,  5,  44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58},
    {19, 80, 81, 68, 5,  94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4,  89, 55, 40},
    {4,  52, 8,  83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7,  97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66},
    {88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3,  46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69},
    {4,  42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8,  46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36},
    {20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4,  36, 16},
    {20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1,  74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5,  54},
    {1,  70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1,  89, 19, 67, 48}
   };


    int horProduct=0, verProduct=0, diagright=0, diagleft=0;
    int maxProduct = 0;

   // horizontal product
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
       {
            horProduct = matr[i][j]*matr[i][j+1]*matr[i][j+2]*matr[i][j+3];
            if(horProduct > maxProduct)
       {
            maxProduct = horProduct;
       }
       }
       
   }
    printf("hori: %d\n", maxProduct);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
       {
            verProduct = matr[i][j]*matr[i+1][j]*matr[i+2][j]*matr[i+3][j];
            if(verProduct > maxProduct)
       {
            maxProduct = verProduct;
       }
       }
       
   }
   
    printf("verti: %d\n", maxProduct);
    
     //diagonal right
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
       {
            diagright = matr[i][j]*matr[i+1][j+1]*matr[i+2][j+2]*matr[i+3][j+3];
            if(diagright > maxProduct)
       {
            maxProduct = diagright;
       }
       }
       
   }

    printf("diagright: %d\n", maxProduct);
   //diagonal left
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
       {
            diagleft = matr[i][j]*matr[i+1][j+1]*matr[i+2][j+2]*matr[i+3][j+3];
            if(diagleft > maxProduct)
       {
            maxProduct = diagleft;
       }
       }
       
   }
   
   printf("diagleft: %d\n", maxProduct);

   
   
return 0;
}
```